# How can I bind select dropdown value as a filter for react table?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am working on a project where I need to fetch data from database and show it on the webpage along with dropdown filters that update the table data dynamically. I am using Synmfony at backend and React on the frontend. I created an API using Symfony which displays data as JSON. Now I imported this data in react using context. but I am not able to bind context with React hooks - usestate to make the filters work.

```
function VehicleTable() {

const context  = useContext(VehicleSearchContext);

console.log(context.vehicles) //returns complete data as array
const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState(context.vehicles); //The problem is here tableData seems to be undefined.

//hooks for dropdown menu
const [selectedProd, setSelectedProd] = React.useState("");
const bike_prod = [...new Set(context.vehicles.map(vehicle => vehicle.bike_producer))]

const handleBikeProdChange = (event) => { 
        setSelectedProd(event.target.value);
        // let _vals = event.target.value ? tableData.filter(r => r.bike_producer === event.target.value) : tableData;
        // // setTableData(_vals);
    } 

return(
        <div>
            <Select style={{ width: "20%" }}
            value={selectedProd}
            onChange={handleBikeProdChange}
            name="bike_producer"
            displayEmpty
            className={classes.selectEmpty}>
                {bike_prod.map(producer => (
                    <MenuItem key={producer} value={producer}>{producer}</MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Select>

<TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table} size='small'>
            <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                <TableCell />
                    <TableCell>Vehicle ID</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Bike Producer</TableCell>

</TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>

        {(rowsPerPage > 0
            ? context.vehicles.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
            : context.vehicles
          ).map((vehicle) => (
            <Row key={vehicle.vehicle_id} row={vehicle}/>
          ))}
</TableBody>
</Table>
        </TableContainer>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: What is happening and what are you expecting to happen? You mention that "tableData  seems to be undefined.", why do you think that? Your `MenuItems` are being generated using `bike_prod`, which is calculated from `context.vehicle`. You're coping `context.vehicle` into the `tableData` state, and in `handleBikeProdChange` you update that state filter the values, but then this isn't being used in your HTML template at all?

Comment: So I am fetching data from the API using context. This data is displayed in 4 dropdown menus and the data table. The dropdowns will act as filters to the table. I am trying to create a functionality where I select an option from dropdown, it asynchronously updates other dropdowns as well as the data table with filtered rows.

The complete code can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/aaygupta/980e5428e36a60312157c81a2d133926